# Get null value after filled value in SQL

Tags: sql, count, databricks

I need to perform a count of how many records in the Accounts ids column had a null value in the Lead Source column, after having a Valid LeadSource (valid LeadSource is just a LeadSource not null)

There are same Account ID and exists values null and not null I need count values null that exists another values not null.
[Table that exists values null and not null for same account ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUC0p.png)

I try with CTE and subquery but I can't reach result expectated.

Comment: can you please share your expected share

Comment: I need count all value that first value AccountID is not null and second value null. for example:
ACCOUNTID | LEAD
123               | 37464
123               | NULL

I need count all value after first value not null that is null

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
select account_id,
sum(case when leadsource is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_count,
sum(case when leadsource is not null then 1 else 1 end) as not_null_count
from table_name group by account_id
```